# #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 for mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

when I am trying to call the following sp code, it giving the above error.
The number of argument is equal

```
drop procedure if exists add_post_with_name;
create procedure add_post_with_name(  in_author_name int ,in_title varchar(150),in_content text , in_html text, in_slug varchar(250),in_post_type varchar(50) , in_url tinyint)  
begin
    declare post_id int default 0;
    declare author_id int default 0;

    select id into author_id from user_profile where user_name = in_author_name;
    if ( author_id ) then
      insert into post (title,content,html,slug,post_type,url,author_id)
              values (in_title,in_content,in_html,in_slug,in_post_type,in_url);
      select id into post_id from post where id = last_insert_id();

      if ( in_post_type = 'SCHOLARSHIP' or in_post_type = 'JOB'
          or in_post_type = 'QUESTION' or in_post_type = 'BLOG' or in_post_type = 'SOCIAL BOOKMARK' ) then
          insert into post_hierarchy_rel (child_post_id) values (post_id);
      end if;
      select post_id;
    else
      select 0;
    end if;

end;$$
```

I am making the call in phpmyadmin as per the below code ...Its throwing the above error.

```
SET @p0='temp'; 
SET @p1='asdddddddd'; 
SET @p2='aaaaaaaaaaaa'; 
SET @p3='aaaaaaaaaaaaa'; 
SET @p4='aaaaaaaaaa'; 
SET @p5='JOB'; 
SET @p6='1'; 

CALL `add_post_with_name`(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6 );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the error in your procedure

```
insert into post (title,content,html,
slug,post_type,url,author_id) <-- here you have 7 columns
values (in_title,in_content,in_html,
in_slug,in_post_type,in_url); <-- only 6 values supplied
```

Since you are already getting `author_id` per your posted code

```
declare author_id int default 0;

select id into author_id from user_profile where user_name = in_author_name;
```

Your actual insert should then be

```
insert into post (title,content,html,
slug,post_type,url,author_id)
values (in_title,in_content,in_html,
in_slug,in_post_type,in_url,author_id); <-- see author_id included as last value
```

Comment: I have declared the `author_id` in the stored procedure.I am filling the `author_id` using `select id into author_id from user_profile where user_name = in_author_name;`

Comment: @made_in_india, yes true but you need to pass it to the insert statement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The `author_id` is missing in `values`

change:

```
insert into post (title,content,html,slug,post_type,url,author_id)
              values (in_title,in_content,in_html,in_slug,in_post_type,in_url);
```

to:

```
   insert into post (title,content,html,slug,post_type,url,author_id)
                  values (in_title,in_content,in_html,in_slug,in_post_type,in_url, author_id);
```